# Hibernate search - The SearchFactory was not initialized using command prompt

Tags: hibernate, search, lucene

I am using hibernate search 5.9.3.
My code is getting executed and indexes are being created perfectly while running the code using eclipse.
 But when I am running .jar file using command prompt, it is giving following exception. [image]

My code snippet is as follows:

```
factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("1:Search.getFullTextEntityManager(factory.openSession())");
            fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(session);
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("2:fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();");
            try {
                fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("3:fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();");
                try {
                    fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                session.getTransaction().commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
            } 
        }
    });
```

Kindly throw some light on this.

Comment: Instead of showing part of the stack trace in a screenshot, can you remove the screenshot and show the complete stack trace, as formatted text, in the question? [reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365)

Comment: (1) How are you building your JAR? (2) What command are you using to launch your app on the command line? It appears to just be `java -jar AnalysisApplication.jar` - so (3) maybe the required Hibernate (and other) library JARs are not on your classpath. You can [edit] the question to provide this new info.

Comment: @andrewJames I am building the jar in eclipse IDE using the option "Extract required lib into generated JAR".